# Error in react-native-video package(used to run video in react-native)

Tags: android, ubuntu, react-native

I went through the installation process of [react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video)( in android/ubuntu) and tried to run video from the url using following code.

```
    import {Video} from 'react-native-video'
    export default class ReactTest extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <Video source={{uri: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4"}}
                 ref={(ref) => {
                   this.player = ref
                 }}                             
                 rate={1.0}                     
                 volume={1.0}                   
                 muted={false}                  
                 paused={false}                 
                 resizeMode="cover"             
                 repeat={true}                  
                 playInBackground={false}       
                 playWhenInactive={false}       
                 progressUpdateInterval={250.0} 
          />

        );
      }
    }
```

But this throws following error:

[image: Error Image]

Can somebody please point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Long shot, but try `import Video from 'react-native-video'` (without import destructuring)

Comment: @zvona This worked for me.Thanks.